# Android Share Intent is Blank for facebook

Tags: android, facebook-share, share-intent

In my app i have share feature to share simple text. Its work for all app but when send on fb its blank. there is no message display.
Below is my code -

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mEventDetailModel.name);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

how to share text on fb.

TIA

Comment: do you want to use FB local native app to share or share without FB local app?

Comment: in both case if facebook app is available then using it if not then browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code samples mentioned here for a complete clear definition on sharing on Facebook from Android
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: I dont want to use SDK, Just simple Share using Intent is require.